# Can the session principal in security config be reused in spring security server?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-authorization-server

I have a class LoginUser that implements UserDetails.

I also have a class CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider that extends DaoAuthenticationProvider.

I am using Spring Security 5 and Spring Authoration Server version 0.3.1.

In OAuth2 process, authorization code grant type, the user needs to login to allow the client program to get the authorization code and token.

When logging in,the username and password is set in the LoginUser w/c is done inside CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider.

The expected result is that LoginUser will become a session Principal of the authentication.

When requesting in an endpoint, the @AuthenticationPrincipal annotated parameter in the endpoint method will be able to get the LoginUser....but what I get is null causing an NPE when I assume a LoginUser was the value.

How will I configure it in the spring authorization server config class?

Or should I configure it only in security config class? how?

Below is my SecurityConfig class:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Slf4j
public class SessionAuthSecurityConfig {
  public static final String LOGOUT_URL = "/logout";
  public static final String LOGIN_URL = "/login";
  private static final String Custom_SESSION = "Custom_SESSION";

  private final AuthenticationEventPublisher authenticationEventPublisher;
  private final UserDetailsService CustomUserDetailsService;
  private final CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider;
  private final ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;
  private final UserService userService;
  private final AuthenticationConfiguration configuration;
  private final CustomWebAuthenticationDetailsSource customWebAuthenticationDetailsSource;

  @Value("${security.enable-csrf:true}")
  public boolean csrfEnabled;

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement(
            c ->
                c.invalidSessionStrategy(this.invalidSessionStrategy())
                    .maximumSessions(CustomFeatureService.getMaxSession())
                    .expiredSessionStrategy(this.expiredSessionStrategy()))
        .cors()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling(
            c ->
                c.accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint()))
        .csrf(
            c -> {
              log.debug("csrfEnabled = {}", csrfEnabled);
              if (csrfEnabled) {
                c.requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new CsrfRequestMatcher())
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
              } else {
                c.disable();
              }
            })
        .authorizeRequests(
            c ->
                c.antMatchers(
                        "/", "/api/**", "/user/**", "/oauth2/authorize")
                    .hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                    .antMatchers(
                        "/rest-api/admin/**")
                    .hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/link/**", "/login-info", "/reissue-password/**")
                    .permitAll())
        .authorizeHttpRequests(c -> c.mvcMatchers("/Custom-lib/**", "/webjars/**").permitAll())
        .formLogin(
            c ->
                c.authenticationDetailsSource(CustomWebAuthenticationDetailsSource)
                    .loginPage(LOGIN_URL)
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
                    .successHandler(successHandler())
                    .failureHandler(failureHandler())
                    .permitAll())
        .logout(
            c ->
                c.permitAll()
                    .logoutUrl(LOGOUT_URL)
                    .addLogoutHandler(eventSaveLogoutHandler()) // Save Logout Event
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .deleteCookies(Custom_SESSION)
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler()) // Redirect
            )
        .addFilterBefore(new UserIpBlockFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    return http.build();
  }

  @Autowired
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider);
  }

  @Bean
  public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
  }

  private AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler() {
    return new CustomAuthFailureHandler(CustomSystemProperties, httpMessageConverter);
  }

  private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    var handler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    return handler;
  }
  

  private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
    var httpStatusEntryPoint = new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    var entryPoints = new LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, AuthenticationEntryPoint>();
    entryPoints.put(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/**"), httpStatusEntryPoint);
    entryPoints.put(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/system-api/**"), httpStatusEntryPoint);
    var delegate = new DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint(entryPoints);
    delegate.setDefaultEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(LOGIN_URL));
    return delegate;
  }

  private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
    AccessDeniedHandlerImpl defaultHandler = new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl();
    defaultHandler.setErrorPage("/access-denied");
    final RequestMatcher apiMatcher = this.apiMatcher();
    return (request, response, accessDeniedException) -> {
      boolean matched = apiMatcher.matches(request);
      if (matched) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
      } else {
        defaultHandler.handle(request, response, accessDeniedException);
      }
    };
  }

  LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler() {
    SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler handler = new SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler();
    handler.setDefaultTargetUrl(LOGIN_URL);
    return handler;
  }

  LogoutHandler eventSaveLogoutHandler() {
    return (request, response, authentication) -> {
      if (authentication == null || authentication.getPrincipal() == null) {
        log.debug("Not authenticated.");
        return;
      }

      LoginUser loginUser = (LoginUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
      String hostName = HttpRequestHelper.getHostName(request);
      String ipAddress = HttpRequestHelper.getIpAddress(request);
      User user = userService.getUser(loginUser.getId()).orElseThrow();
      eventQueueSendingService.sendLogoutEvent(user, ipAddress, hostName);
    };
  }
}
```

This is the auth server config class:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfig {

  @Autowired private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
  @Autowired private ApiAccessLogService apiAccessLogService;
  @Autowired private HttpServletRequest request;
  @Autowired private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;
  @Autowired private CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider customDaoAuthenticationProvider;
  @Autowired private CustomWebAuthenticationDetailsSource customWebAuthenticationDetailsSource;

  @Bean
  public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
    RegisteredClient registeredClient =
        RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .clientId("ssss")
            .clientSecret(passwordEncoder.encode("123"))
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
            .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:19940/authorized")
            .tokenSettings(tokenSettings())
            .scope("full")
            .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(false).build())
            .build();

    return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
  }

  private AuthenticationConverter customAuthorizationRequestConverter() {
    final OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationConverter delegate = new OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationConverter();

    return (request) -> {
      OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationToken authorizationCodeRequestAuthentication =
        (OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationToken) delegate.convert(request);
      return authorizationCodeRequestAuthentication;
    };
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
  public SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer<HttpSecurity> authorizationServerConfigurer =
      new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer<>();
    RequestMatcher endpointsMatcher = authorizationServerConfigurer
      .getEndpointsMatcher();

    http
      .requestMatcher(endpointsMatcher)
      .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
        authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated()
      )
      .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(endpointsMatcher))
      .apply(authorizationServerConfigurer);
//

    authorizationServerConfigurer
      .authorizationEndpoint(authorizationEndpoint ->
        authorizationEndpoint
          .authorizationRequestConverter(customAuthorizationRequestConverter())
          .authenticationProvider(CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider)
      );

    http
        // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
        // authorization endpoint
        .exceptionHandling(
        (exceptions) ->
            exceptions.authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")));

    return http.build();
    
  }

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationEventPublisher authenticationEventPublisher(
      ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
    return new AuthenticationEventPublisher() {
      @Override
      public void publishAuthenticationSuccess(Authentication authentication) {
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new AuthenticationSuccessEvent(authentication));
        final Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        String clientId = null;
        Integer userId = null;

        if (principal instanceof LoginUser loginUser) {
          userId = loginUser.getId();
        }

        if (authentication instanceof OAuth2Authorization) {
          final OAuth2Authorization oAuth2Authorization = (OAuth2Authorization) authentication;
          clientId = oAuth2Authorization.getRegisteredClientId();
        }
        apiAccessLogService.saveApiAccessLog(
            userId, request, ApiAccessLog.AccessType.OAUTH2, clientId);
      }

      @Override
      public void publishAuthenticationFailure(
          AuthenticationException exception, Authentication authentication) {
        log.debug("OAuth2 authentication failed");
      }
    };
  }

  @Bean
  public ProviderSettings providerSettings() {
    return ProviderSettings.builder().issuer("http://localhost:19940").build();
  }

  @Bean
  public TokenSettings tokenSettings() {
    return TokenSettings.builder()
        .accessTokenFormat(OAuth2TokenFormat.REFERENCE)
        .accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofSeconds(6000L))
        .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public OAuth2AuthorizationService authorizationService() {
    return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizationService();
  }
}
```

CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider extends DaoAuthenticationProvider implements Ordered {

  private final AccountScratchCodeService accountScratchCodeService;
  private final AuthenticationEmailService authenticationEmailService;
  private final Mail2faTokenService mail2faTokenService;
  private final UserService userService;

  private int order = -1;

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    // check if the input authentication is for normal authentication
    if (StringUtils.hasText((String) authentication.getPrincipal())
        && StringUtils.hasText((String) authentication.getCredentials())) {
      SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
      return super.authenticate(authentication);
    }

    // fallback to default authentication check
    return super.authenticate(authentication);
  }

  @Override
  public void additionalAuthenticationChecks(
      UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication)
      throws AuthenticationException {
    LoginUser loginUser = (LoginUser) userDetails;
    Object detailsObj = authentication.getDetails();

    if (detailsObj instanceof CustomWebAuthenticationDetails CustomWebAuthenticationDetails) {

      if (CustomWebAuthenticationDetails.isBasicAuth()) {
        if (!loginUser.isBasicAuthAllowed()) {
          log.debug("Login Failure (User has no permission.)");
          throw new NotAllowedMethodException("Basic Auth is allowed.");
        }
      }

      var userTfaCode = CustomWebAuthenticationDetails.getVerificationCode();
      var userTfaMethod = loginUser.getTwoFa();
      String remoteAddress = CustomWebAuthenticationDetails.getRemoteAddress();
      Locale locale = CustomWebAuthenticationDetails.getLocale();

      if (userTfaMethod == null) {
        // perform default check
        super.additionalAuthenticationChecks(userDetails, authentication);
      }

      if (userTfaMethod != null && userTfaCode == null) {
        // perform default check
        super.additionalAuthenticationChecks(userDetails, authentication);

        if (userTfaMethod == MAIL) {
          sendAuthEmail(loginUser, locale);
          throw new TwoFactorAuthenticationRequiredException(
              "Verification code sent via email.", loginUser, MAIL);
        } else if (userTfaMethod == TOTP) {
          throw new TwoFactorAuthenticationRequiredException(
              "Awaiting verification code from a mobile app.", loginUser, TOTP);
        } else {
          throw new RuntimeException("Unknown two fa method. method=" + userTfaMethod);
        }
      }

      verifyCode(loginUser, userTfaCode);
    }
  }

  private void sendAuthEmail(LoginUser loginUser, Locale locale) {
    String mailAddress = loginUser.getMailAddress();
    User user = userService.getUser(loginUser.getId()).orElseThrow();
    if (!StringUtils.hasText(mailAddress)) {
      throw new MailAuthenticationSendingException("No email specified for email authentication.");
    }

    try {
      authenticationEmailService.sendEmail(user, locale);
    } catch (MessagingException | MailSendException e) {
      throw new MailAuthenticationSendingException("Failed to send authentication email.", e);
    }
  }

  private void verifyCode(LoginUser loginUser, String code) throws AuthenticationException {
    TwoFaType twoFaType = loginUser.getTwoFa();
    if (twoFaType == null) {
      log.debug("Two factor authentication not configured for current user.");
    } else if (twoFaType.equals(MAIL)) {
      verifyMailAuthCode(loginUser, code);
    } else if (twoFaType.equals(TOTP)) {
      verifyTotpCode(loginUser, code);
    }
  }

  private void verifyMailAuthCode(LoginUser loginUser, String code) throws AuthenticationException {
    // Check if the verification code is null or empty
    if (!StringUtils.hasText(code)) {
      throw new TwoFactorAuthenticationException("Empty verification code.", loginUser);
    }

    // Check if the token is recorded in the database
    Mail2faToken token =
        mail2faTokenService
            .find(code)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new TwoFactorAuthenticationException("Token not found.", loginUser));

    // Check if the token is expired
    ZonedDateTime expirationTime = token.getExpirationTime();
    if (expirationTime.isBefore(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()))) {
      mail2faTokenService.delete(token);
      throw new TwoFactorAuthenticationExpiredException("Token expired.");
    }

    // Check that the login user ID matches the user ID registered to the token
    User tokenUser = token.getUser();
    if (!loginUser.getId().equals(tokenUser.getId())) {
      throw new TwoFactorAuthenticationException("Invalid token.", loginUser);
    }

    mail2faTokenService.delete(token);
  }

  private void verifyTotpCode(LoginUser loginUser, String code) throws AuthenticationException {
    // Check if the verification code is null or empty
    if (!StringUtils.hasText(code)) {
      throw new TwoFactorAuthenticationException("Empty verification code.", loginUser);
    }
    // Check if code is non numeric
    if (!code.matches("^\\d+$")) {
      throw new TwoFactorAuthenticationException("Invalid token.", loginUser);
    }

    GoogleAuthenticator gAuth = new GoogleAuthenticator();
    int intCode = Integer.parseInt(code);
    boolean isAuthorized = gAuth.authorize(loginUser.getSecret(), intCode);
    if (!isAuthorized) {
      UserScratchCode usc =
          accountScratchCodeService
              .findByUserIdAndScratchCode(loginUser.getId(), intCode)
              .orElseThrow(() -> new TwoFactorAuthenticationException("Invalid token.", loginUser));
      accountScratchCodeService.delete(usc);
    }
  }

  public int getOrder() {
    return this.order;
  }

  public void setOrder(int i) {
    this.order = i;
  }
}
```

CustomUserDetails

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@Profile("default")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

  private final UserRepository userRepository;
  private final UserPermissionService userPermissionService;
  private final LoginLockoutService loginLockoutService;
  private final LoginUserService loginUserService;
  private final NetworkPermissionService networkPermissionService;

  public CustomUserDetailsService(
      UserRepository userRepository,
      UserPermissionService userPermissionService,
      LoginLockoutService loginLockoutService,
      LoginUserService loginUserService,
      NetworkPermissionService networkPermissionService) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.userPermissionService = userPermissionService;
    this.loginLockoutService = loginLockoutService;
    this.loginUserService = loginUserService;
    this.networkPermissionService = networkPermissionService;
  }

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user =
        userRepository
            .findByUsernameAndNotDeletedTrue(username)
            .orElseThrow(
                () -> {
                  String errorMsg = String.format("Username '%s' not found.", username);
                  log.debug(errorMsg);
                  return new UsernameNotFoundException(errorMsg);
                });
    LoginUser loginUser = loginUserService.getLoginUserByUser(user);

    log.debug("load user : {}", loginUser);

    boolean locked = loginLockoutService.isUserLocked(loginUser);
    loginUser.setLocked(locked);
    loginUser.setExpired(this.calcUserIsExpired(loginUser));

    UserPermission userPermission = userPermissionService.getUserPermission(user);
    loginUser.setBasicAuthAllowed(userPermission.isBasicAuth());

    Set<String> ipRangeList = networkPermissionService.createIpRangeList(user);
    loginUser.setIpRangeList(ipRangeList);

    return loginUser;
  }

  private boolean calcUserIsExpired(LoginUser loginUser) {
    final LocalDateTime expirationDate = loginUser.getExpirationDate();
    return expirationDate != null && expirationDate.isBefore(LocalDateTime.now());
  }
}
```

Comment: please do not "describe" your code in text, it's just a tip, post your code if you want actual help.

Comment: Yes, please post your security configuration and custom classes (since they are relevant to your question). As I mentioned in another question, I suspect you can simplify your configuration and not need to use a custom authentication provider at all.

Comment: hi, I added the code above

Comment: Can you share any part of your CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider and UserDetailsService? I’m still not clear on why you need a custom authentication provider.

Comment: hi, I added this 2 classes CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider and UserDetailsService. Been trying to set this in the OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your provided code, it seems you're working through an implementation of an authorization server with multi-factor authentication. You are currently attempting to combine authorization server endpoints (the Authorization Endpoint) with the user authentication flow.

> How will I configure it in the spring authorization server config class?
>
> Or should I configure it only in security config class?

I would strongly recommend focusing on multi-factor authentication in the security configuration, not in the authorization server config. I would also recommend implementing your authentication flow separately first (build a separate application for prototyping/testing), and test it to ensure it working before adding the authorization server dependency.

I can't say for sure if your `CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider` will work as-is since it is quite complex, but take a look at an alternative approach to multi-factor authentication in the [Spring Security mfa sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/authentication/username-password/mfa).

Once you've reviewed and tried out that sample, take a look at this [Spring Authorization Server mfa sample](https://github.com/sjohnr/spring-authorization-server/tree/mfa-sample/samples/mfa-authorizationserver) which uses concepts from the Spring Security sample and builds on them. When reviewing the second sample, please notice that configuration for multi-factor authentication and all custom implementation logic is kept completely separate from authorization server configuration.

**Note** that the authz server sample is on a slightly stale branch at the moment.

Comment: hi, thank you for the idea...I will check on it.